# Using JARs in WEB-INF/lib with previous versions of Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, servlets, jar

I'm working on a way to add plugin-like functionality to an application.

What I'd like is to be able to give a client a JAR file and have them drop it into the application and have it be "pulled in" without having to make any changes to config files or whatnot.

I would love to be able to put them into `WEB-INF/lib`, which works great with Tomcat 7 since it supports Servlet 3.0. The problem is that not all users of this application have Tomcat 7, and this needs to be flexible enough to not force them to update.

Does anyone know of a way to achieve the same functionality, but in a way that's compatible with older versions of Tomcat and the Servlet API?

This is also a Maven project, so pushing it to the repo could work as well, but that involves the client modifying `pom.xml` which I'd rather stay away from.

**Edit:**

I think I found a suitable solution using serviceLoader, but if anyone has a better idea let me know. I'm pretty new to this area so I'm open to advice.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to accomplish? Have the new functionality with a restart? Have new servlets available? Or just do a classpath scan on startup to identify/initialize/etc. whatever functionality is provided by the plugins?

Comment: @DaveNewton The plugins will vary, but most will consist of a jsp and a HTML response class to handle the redirection to that page. Thus, they wouldn't be loaded until called. Loading on startup of the server is of course fine as well, as a Maven dependency would do.

Answer (score 0):

You can drop JAR files directly into WEB-INF/lib on older versions of Tomcat as well.

You just need to make sure that the JAR files work on the version of Tomcat they are being dropped in. So either

> a) Make the JAR file work for all required Tomcat versions
>
> b) Create different versions of the JAR for each tomcat version and
>   distribute accordingly.

---

The problem with this, is that if the web application is redeployed from scratch, the plugin JARs may be deleted.  So you may need to think about how to persist them.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Maven WAR overlays if you want to make the customization explicit and repeatable: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html